# Noise of archers, disturbers or of those who distribute water?

Tags: word-study, translation-philosophy, judges, word-choice

In Judges 5:11 there's different translations as to who does the noise.

- In KJV

> They that are delivered from the **noise of archers** in the places of drawing water, there shall they rehearse the righteous acts of the LORD, even the righteous acts toward the inhabitants of his villages in Israel: then shall the people of the LORD go down to the gates.

- In BST

> ye that are delivered from the **noise of disturbers** among the drawers of water; there shall they relate righteous acts: O Lord, increase righteous acts in Israel: then the people of the Lord went down to the cities.

- In NASB

> “At the **sound of those who distribute water** among the watering places, There they will recount the righteous deeds of the LORD, The righteous deeds for His peasantry in Israel. Then the people of the LORD went down to the gates.

How to determine which is more likely to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending word here is מְחַֽצְצִ֗ים (G2686). It appears only 3 times in the OT. According to an NIV note: The meaning of the Hebrew for this word is uncertain.

מְחַֽצְצִ֗ים (mə·ḥaṣ·ṣîm)
Verb - Piel - Participle - masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 2686: To chop into, pierce, sever, to curtail, to **distribute**, to **shoot** an arrow

How to determine which is more likely to be correct?

There are only 3 usages of this word in the OT.
Because it involves so little agreement and so much uncertainty, it is a game of frequency and probability.

In https://biblehub.com/judges/5-11.htm,
7 versions use "musicians" or "singers",
7 use "archers",
5 use "divide",
only Brenton Septuagint Translation uses "disturbers",
and only NASB uses "distribute".

In any case, I woundn't bet money on any of them.